# CSS Next to my Round Corners are too much pixel

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, pixel

i've created a layout that contains round corners made with CSS. The corners are displayed correctly, but next to them there are too much pixels.
I checked my graphics, but they do not contain these pixels.

Here's my CSS-Code:

```
<style>
div.box {background:url(fld_sel_center_left.png) repeat-y;}
div.box div {background:url(fld_sel_center_right.png) right repeat-y;}
div.box div div {background:url(fld_sel_head_background.png) repeat-x;}
div.box div div div {background:url(fld_sel_buttom_center.png) bottom repeat-x;}
div.box div div div div {background:url(fld_sel_head_left.png) left top no-repeat;}
div.box div div div div div {background:url(fld_sel_head_right.png) right top no-repeat;}
div.box div div div div div div {background:url(fld_sel_buttom_left.png) left bottom no-repeat;}
div.box div div div div div div div {background:url(fld_sel_buttom_right.png) right bottom no-repeat;}

div.content{padding: 40px 10px 15px 20px;}
</style>
```

and the HTML-Code for the DIVs:

```
<div class="box">
 <div>
      <div>
           <div>
                <div>
                     <div>
                          <div>
                               <div>
                                    <div class="content">
                                          content<br />
                                           content<br />
                                           content<br />
                                           content<br />
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

And here you see the problem:

[image]

Comment: “next to them there are too much pixels” — I’m afraid I don’t understand what that means. Could you add a screenshot that shows what the problem is? (There’s a button above the question edit box that lets you upload an image.)

Comment: http://oi43.tinypic.com/1zbulnq.jpg this is the link to the picture. i'm not allowed to upload directly.

Comment: The `<div>`itis, it hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you not heard of the border-radius property (for all browser) and CSS3PIE (for old IE)?

Just use:

```
<div class="content">
content<br />
</div>
```

then in CSS

```
.content {
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

Then read the documentation on [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) if you need it to work in old IE.

Comment: That's a nice thing - i will bookmark it.
But the problem is, that i must use these images, which build the round corner.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with these attributes:

bottom:
width:
height:
margin-top:
margin-bottom:
margin-left:
margin-right:
padding-left:
padding-right:

for instance, the code below will create one large blue box with one smaller white box in the center of it:

CSS:

```
.box
{
position:absolute;

width:30%;
height:30%;   
margin-left: 10%;
margin-top: 30%; 
margin-right: 5px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 5px;
text-align: center;

background: white;


}

.workarea {
    position:absolute;

width:10%;
height:10%;   
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
text-align: center;

background: blue;


}
```

html:

```
</head>
<body>

        <div id="workarea" class="workarea">
              <div id="box" class="box">
              </div>
         </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include `margin:0` and `padding:0` for the div's.  I guess this problem depends on the browser.  Have you checked with other browsers and can you include the images as well?

Also you may try `z-index` by assigning the div's `position:absolute` and put them on top of each other to avoid spaces.

Comment: I use IE but also check with Firefox and the result is the same. With margin and padding there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing your background images contain the blue colour. You’ll need to amend the CSS so that the background images don’t overlap each other.

Without seeing the actual background images you’re working with it’s a bit difficult to be more specific.